# "Fatal Error" when loading a dll?

Tags: java, dll

EDIT: I (sortof) figured this out. If I don't let my jar export the dlls, but instead manually put them in, it works fine. Now, my question is, how do I export the dlls CORRECTLY from inside my jar?

What is this? The reason I need to load some dlls is because I am using java3d, and I am trying to bundle it with the jar file instead of making people install it. Eclipse takes care of the jar files, but that leaves me to handle the dlls. Whenever I run my program, when a dll gets loaded, the whole jvm crashes. (Note that if I don't load the dlls, java 3d automatically tries system.loadLibrary())
Here is what comes out:

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x772de9d7, pid=8044, tid=7616
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (7.0_67-b01) (build 1.7.0_67-b01)

# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (24.65-b04 mixed mode, sharing windows-x86)

# Problematic frame:
# C  [ntdll.dll+0x3e9d7]
#
# Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client vers
ions of Windows
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# C:\Users\bram.zerbe\Desktop\test\hs_err_pid8044.log
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#
```

Does anybody have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Everything is all fixed up now, what I think was happening was that the byte[] that I was reading and writing with was bigger than needed, and didn't work. all fixed now